# jQuery: undefined displayed

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

I'd like to display the percentage of progress below jQueryUI progress bar.

HTML:

```
<div class="progressbar_container">
    <div id="progressbar" class="progressbar_child"></div>
    <div id="percent" style="text-align: center;"></div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(function () {
    var count = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        count = count + 1;
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({
            max: 10,
            value: count,
            change: function (event, ui) {
                $("#percent").html(ui.value);
            }
        });
    }, 500);
});
```

But, it displays: undefined %.
Also, it displays it a bit after the progress started, which means: 2, 3... It doesn't display: 0, 1...

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ui` argument in change event is a dummy placeholder as indicated in the **[docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/#event-change)**.

You need to use the **[value](http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/#method-value)** method for getting the value.

```
...
change: function (event, ui) {
    $("#percent").html($("#progressbar").progressbar( "value" ));
}
...
```

Comment: Ok. That works. But, it doesn't start displaying 0, 1... ? It starts from 2, 3...